# Custom MaterialFrame control with only one platform renderer

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I have MaterialFrame custom control.

iOS renderer works great and looks like:

```
public class MaterialFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    private const int ShadowColor = 0x939393;

    public override void Draw(
        CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        // Update shadow to match better material design standards of elevation
        Layer.ShadowRadius = Layer.CornerRadius;
        Layer.ShadowColor = ColorHelper.FromHex(ShadowColor).CGColor;
        Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(1, 1);
        Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.30f;
        Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
        Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
    }
}
```

On Android platform I want to use implementation based on my other cross-platform control. My .net standard(shared project) implementation:

```
public class MaterialFrame : Frame
{
    public MaterialFrame()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            Content = new MyOtherCustomControl
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this implementation doesn't work on Android. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I create the `MyOtherCustomControl`.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Text="MyOtherCustomControl"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button />
</StackLayout>
```

And use it in `MaterialFrame` custom control.

```
public class MaterialFrame : Frame
{
    public MaterialFrame()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            Content = new MyOtherCustomControl
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red
            };
        }
    }

}
```

Usage of MaterialFrame:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <pages:MaterialFrame />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Screenshot:

[image]